# Sliding Material Design Card View

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am writing a web ap which looks like this:

[image]

Instead of stacking a bunch of cards like in the image above, I want to try and have a slider that when swiped the next card is displayed.

My html looks like this:

```
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Starter Template - Materialize</title>

</head>

<body style="">

    <div class="navbar-fixed ">
        <nav class="orange " role="navigation">
            <div id="replaceBar" class="nav-wrapper container">
                <a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">Statistics</a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down left">
                    <li><a href="stats.html">Statistics</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul style="left: -250px;" id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav left">
                    <li><a href="stats.html">Statistics</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="img/menuIcon.png" height="30" width="30"></a>
                <ul id="search" class="right valign-wrapper">
                    <li class="valign">
                        <a href="#"> <img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="img/searchIcon.png" height="30" width="30"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

    </div>




    <div class="row" style="margin:1;">
        <div class="col s12 m7">
            <div class="card valign-wrapper">
                <div class="card-content valign center-block">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h3 id="beerCount" class="center-align orange-text text-darken-2">410</h3>
                        <p class="center-align">Beers Tasted</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="margin:1;">
        <div class="col s12 m7">
            <div class="card valign-wrapper">
                <div class="card-content valign center-block">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h3 id="breweryCount" class="center-align orange-text text-darken-2">161</h3>
                        <p class="center-align">Breweries Tried</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="margin:1;">
        <div class="col s12 m7">
            <div class="card valign-wrapper">
                <div class="card-content valign center-block">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h3 id="breweryVisit" class="center-align orange-text text-darken-2">16</h3>
                        <p class="center-align">Breweries Visited</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>







    <!-- Modal Structure -->
    <div style="z-index: 1003; display: none; opacity: 0; transform: scaleX(0.7); top: 0px;" id="modal1" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content center">
            <div>
                <span class="card-title">99 bottles of beer on the wall...</span>
            </div>
            <div id="load" class="preloader-wrapper big active ">
                <div class="spinner-layer spinner-yellow-only">
                    <div class="circle-clipper left">
                        <div class="circle"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gap-patch">
                        <div class="circle"></div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="circle-clipper right">
                        <div class="circle"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>




<div style="left: 0px;" class="drag-target"></div><div class="hiddendiv common"></div></body></html>
```

I tried adding them to an image slider that is offered with materializecss which is what I am using to build my web app but it didnt work.

Anyway to slide them with html5 and css?

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mjbbc48h/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace the image content in the materializecss slider with your card element. Like so:

```
<div class="slider">
<ul class="slides">
  <li>
     <div class="row" style="margin:1;">
    <div class="col s12 m7">
        <div class="card valign-wrapper">
            <div class="card-content valign center-block">
                <div class="row">
                    <h3 id="breweryVisit" class="center-align orange-text text-darken-2">16</h3>
                    <p class="center-align">Breweries Visited</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="row" style="margin:1;">
    <div class="col s12 m7">
        <div class="card valign-wrapper">
            <div class="card-content valign center-block">
                <div class="row">
                    <h3 id="beerCount" class="center-align orange-text text-darken-2">410</h3>
                    <p class="center-align">Beers Tasted</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This should give you what you are looking for. Remember to initialize the slider.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, just a grey box. But on further exploration I also got a grey box while trying an image. I think I might be missing something else too

Comment: Remember to initialize the plugin with:

    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider').slider();
});

Comment: I will try that when I get back to my computer, thanks.

Comment: So that kind of works. My card is in there, but the container is huge and doesn't match to the card side. Check out this screenshot:

http://postimg.org/image/cyf5y1gxv/